# Flutter listView isn't updating after deleting items

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm using a list view to display some items and also I'm using [flutter_tindercard](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard)

to approve or refuse items when an item is approved it should be added to the approved items list then removed from the list view , and the same for refused items , but the issue when the item is refused or approved it is not removing from the list view.

**PS: the bottom elements are not moving to the top**

---

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tindercard/flutter_tindercard.dart';

class ExampleHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleHomePageState createState() => _ExampleHomePageState();
}

class _ExampleHomePageState extends State<ExampleHomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List approved = [];
  List refused = [];

  List<String> welcomeImages = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631636176993-759dea1a1300?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631634176568-f543af6a41de?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631691971564-adf9419d904e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxM3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631641906574-24adb8594649?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642702821-c8da6771f0c6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631621461675-e61a1f28d3d6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0NHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
  ];
  List<TinderCarder> cards = [];
  CardController controller = CardController(); //Use this to trigger swap.

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    cards = welcomeImages.map((element) {
      return TinderCarder(
        image: element,
        controller: controller,
        onLeftPress: () {
          setState(() {
            cards.removeAt(element.indexOf(element));
            print('index is: ' + "${element.indexOf(element)}");
            print('list length: ' + cards.length.toString());
          });
        },
        onRightPress: () {
          setState(() {
            cards.removeAt(element.indexOf(element));
            print('index is: ' + "${element.indexOf(element)}");
            print('list length: ' + cards.length.toString());
          });
        },
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView(
          children: cards,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TinderCarder extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  Function onLeftPress;
  Function onRightPress;
  var controller;

  TinderCarder(
      {required this.image,
      this.controller,
      required this.onLeftPress,
      required this.onRightPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: TinderSwapCard(
        orientation: AmassOrientation.BOTTOM,
        totalNum: 1,
        stackNum: 3,
        swipeEdge: 4.0,
        maxWidth: double.infinity,
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        cardBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
          child: Image.network(
            image,
            width: double.infinity,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        cardController: controller,
        swipeUpdateCallback: (DragUpdateDetails details, Alignment align) {
          /// Get swiping card's alignment
          if (align.x < 0) {
          } else if (align.x > 0) {}
        },
        swipeCompleteCallback: (CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index) {
          print(orientation.toString());
          if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.LEFT) {
            print("Card is LEFT swiping");
            // print(welcomeImages.length);
            onLeftPress();
          } else if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.RIGHT) {
            print("Card is RIGHT swiping");
            // print(welcomeImages.length);
            onRightPress();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: one]

[image: two]

Comment: i update my answer, you just update your image list `swipeCompleteCallback ` but you wanted to update from `swipeUpdateCallback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

Try with `setstate`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tindercard/flutter_tindercard.dart';

class ExampleHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleHomePageState createState() => _ExampleHomePageState();
}

class _ExampleHomePageState extends State<ExampleHomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List approved = [];
  List refused = [];

  List<String> welcomeImages = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631636176993-759dea1a1300?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631634176568-f543af6a41de?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631691971564-adf9419d904e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxM3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631641906574-24adb8594649?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642702821-c8da6771f0c6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631621461675-e61a1f28d3d6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw0NHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
  ];
  List<TinderCarder> cards = [];
  CardController controller = CardController(); //Use this to trigger swap.

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    cards = welcomeImages.map((element) {
      return TinderCarder(
        image: element,
        controller: controller,
        onLeftPress: () {
          setState(() {
            cards.removeAt(element.indexOf(element));
            print('index is: ' + "${element.indexOf(element)}");
            print('list length: ' + cards.length.toString());
          });
        },
        onRightPress: () {
          setState(() {
            cards.removeAt(element.indexOf(element));
            print('index is: ' + "${element.indexOf(element)}");
            print('list length: ' + cards.length.toString());
          });
        },
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            key: Key(cards.length.toString()),
            physics: ScrollPhysics(),
            children: cards,
          ),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}

class TinderCarder extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  Function onLeftPress;
  Function onRightPress;
  var controller;

  TinderCarder(
      { this.image,
        this.controller,
         this.onLeftPress,
         this.onRightPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: TinderSwapCard(
        orientation: AmassOrientation.BOTTOM,
        totalNum: 1,
        stackNum: 3,
        swipeEdge: 4.0,
        maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        cardBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
          child: Image.network(
            image,
            width: double.infinity,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        cardController: controller,
        swipeUpdateCallback: (DragUpdateDetails details, Alignment align) {
          /// Get swiping card's alignment
          if (align.x < 0) {
          } else if (align.x > 0) {}
        },
        swipeCompleteCallback: (CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index) {
          print(orientation.toString());
          if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.LEFT) {
            print("Card is LEFT swiping");
            // print(welcomeImages.length);
            onLeftPress();
          } else if (orientation == CardSwipeOrientation.RIGHT) {
            print("Card is RIGHT swiping");
            // print(welcomeImages.length);
            onRightPress();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your message but when delete item the card becomes white empty

Comment: Updated answer, you used listview and each item took only single image that's why it shows empty

Comment: updated my answer and here is your solution, if it is helpful for you please mark as answer

Comment: great, now it left one single issue which is  when the item is deleted its place stays empty

Comment: when all item deleted it will show empty if you want to add any message like "there is no image"

Comment: I meant when an item is deleted the bottom items should go to the top, it seems we need to define a list of Swipecards

Comment: if you remove it from the bottom it works but from the top it not works, and don't get further documentation to help you

Comment: After all, got solution. update my answer Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237129/discussion-between-braken-mohamed-and-jahidul-islam).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using stateful widget then apply setstate() to build again your widget.
If you want to use stateless widget than use state management like GetX or provider.
For GetX create observable list in controller and wrap widget with obx so whenever list is updated the obx will build that particular widget for you again.
To Learn GetX Properly go through this playlist created by tadas petra.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL26uY6-lIzqkmvpNr9gMCrIvl8k5Mqrhs

Comment: please check my question again